# Adding custom shapes in Cocoa

Tags: cocoa

Does anyone know how to add custom shapes (e.g. a circle, a triangle, a hexagon, etc) into a Cocoa application? Should I use some special object? Thanks.

Do not say something like adding a picture with custom shape. I want to change the color of the shape to do my project.

Comment: Are you asking how to programmatically draw a shape in Cocoa? Your question isn't all that clear.

Answer (score 1):

You can make any shape you want out of bezier curves using the `NSBezierPath` class ([class documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/nsbezierpath_Class/Reference/Reference.html)).

Here's a category and class method for drawing polygons (pentagons, hexagons, et cetera).

```
@interface NSBezierPath (Polygons)
+ (NSBezierPath *)bezierPathWithPolygonAt:(NSPoint)origin
    radius:(float)r sides:(int)nsides;
@end

@implementation
+ (NSBezierPath *)bezierPathWithPolygonAt:(NSPoint)origin
    radius:(float)r sides:(int)nsides
{
    NSBezierPath *p = [NSBezierPath bezierPath];
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < nsides; ++i) {
        float a = i * (atanf(1.0f) * 8.0f / nsides);
        NSPoint pt = NSMakePoint(origin.x + r * cosf(a),
                                 origin.y + r * sinf(a));
        if (i == 0)
            [p moveToPoint:pt];
        else
            [p lineToPoint:pt];
    }
    [p closePath];
    return p;
}
@end
```

Answer (score 0):

I think for You is the best to use Quartz graphic.

> Quartz is at the center of all graphics in Cocoa. It provides basic graphics data structures and drawing routines.

Look at this two tutorials it will be helpful for You:

[Intro to Quartz](http://cocoadevcentral.com/d/intro_to_quartz/).

[Intro to Quartz II](http://cocoadevcentral.com/d/intro_to_quartz_two/).

In Quartz You can draw any shape and change color easily.